# cannot access parent datacontext and bind to click event

Tags: knockout.js

Even after looking at the working example found here: http://jsfiddle.net/tsenyi/FCFRE/
I am unable to access the parent context of my data from a foreach binding. I want to handle the click event of the remove button in the order detail table.
Several other questions similar to mine have pointed to item 2 in the knockout documentation found here:
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html

Due to my limited intellectual abilities I am unable to grasp why the above document solves my issue. Please assist me with that.

Notes:
This button in the header fires the remove handler.  Its just a test:

```
<input type="button" value="Remove = this works" data-bind="click:RemoveLineItem" />
```

This is the broken button (this is the problem that is the subject of this question).  I do not attempt to pass $index to my handler here.  I will need to do that but I removed the code for debugging purposes:

```
<td><input type="button" value="Remove - this does not work" data-bind="click: $root.RemoveLineItem"/></td>
```

For the record: note that the sample data created in my view model in the document ready function adds two orderDetail objects to the order detail object.  When I remove the data-bind statement from the button, both data rows are rendered.  The as shown below causes only one row to render.  I have no idea why obviously I am doing something wrong.

jquery version = 2.1.1
knockout version = 3.1.0

The javascript file shown below is loaded by a master page so the script element is not shown in my html.  All bindings except the issue stated above work as expected.

```
    <form data-bind="submit:submitOrder">
<div>
    <div data-bind="with: Hdr">
        <p>ID: <input data-bind="value:ID" /></p>
        <p>Order Date: <input data-bind="value:OrderDate" /></p>
        <p>Customer Name: <input data-bind="value:CustomerName" /></p>
        <p>Customer City:<input data-bind="value:CustomerCity" /></p>

    </div>

    <input type="button" value="Remove = this works" data-bind="click:RemoveLineItem" />
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Row ID</th>
                <th>Item ID</th>
                <th>Item Desc</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Ext</th>
                <th>Remove</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody data-bind="foreach: Dtl">
            <tr>
                <td><input data-bind="value: ID" /></td>
                <td><input data-bind="value: ItemID" /></td>
                <td><input data-bind="value: Description" /></td>
                <td><input data-bind="value: Qty" /></td>
                <td><input data-bind="value: Price" /></td>
                <td><input data-bind="value: Ext" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" value="Remove - this does not work" data-bind="click: $root.RemoveLineItem"/></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

// javascript...


var today = function () {
    this.now = new Date();
    this.dd = now.getDate();
    this.mm = now.getMonth() + 1;
    this.yy = now.getFullYear();
    if (dd < 10) { dd = '0' + dd }
    if (mm < 10) { mm = '0' + mm }
    return mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yy;
}

var orderHeader = function (id, orderDate, customerName, customerCity) {
    this.ID = ko.observable(id);
    this.OrderDate = ko.observable(orderDate);
    this.CustomerName = ko.observable(customerName);
    this.CustomerCity = ko.observable(customerCity);
};

var orderDetail = function (id, orderID, itemID, description, qty, price) {
    var self = this;
    this.ID = ko.observable(id);
    this.OrderID = ko.observable(orderID);
    this.ItemID = ko.observable(itemID);
    this.Description = ko.observable(description);
    this.Qty = ko.observable(qty);
    this.Price = ko.observable(price);
    this.Ext = ko.computed(function () { return self.Qty() * self.Price() }, orderDetail);
};

// ---------------------------

var sales = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.blue = ko.observable(30);
    self.orange = ko.observable(14);
    self.pink = ko.observable(44);
    self.showPurple = ko.observable(true);
};

var viewModel = function (hdr, dtl, sales) {
    var self = this;
    self.Hdr = ko.observable(hdr);
    self.Dtl = ko.observableArray(dtl);
    self.Sales = ko.observable(sales);
    self.RemoveLineItem = function () {
        //Dtl.splice(index, 1);
        alert('RemoveLineItem was called');
    };

    self.submitOrder = function () {
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245905/fetching-or-sending-data-from-a-form-using-knockout-js
        var hdr = {
            ID: self.Hdr().ID(),
            OrderDate: self.Hdr().OrderDate(),
            CustomerName: self.Hdr().CustomerName(),
            CustomerCity: self.Hdr().CustomerCity()
        };
        $.post("/api/OrderAPI/SubmitOrderHeader", hdr, function (response) { alert('submitted'); });

    }

    self.gridViewModel = new ko.simpleGrid.viewModel({
        data: this.Dtl, columns:
            [
                { headerText: "ID", rowText: "ID", width: 230 },
                { headerText: "ItemID", rowText: "ItemID", width: 280 },
                { headerText: "Description", rowText: "Description", width: 430 }
            ]

    });
};


$(document).ready(function () {

    var orderOne = new orderHeader(1, today(), 'sam', 'manhattan beach');
    var details = [
        new orderDetail(1, 1, 10, 'laptop', 3, 2300),
        new orderDetail(2, 1, 36, 'mouse', 2, 18)
    ];
    var sls = new sales();
    //ko.applyBindings(new orderHeader(0,new Date(),'Sam','Santa Monica'));
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel(orderOne, details, sls));
});
```

Comment: Have you tried `$parent` instead of `$root`? It looks like you want to go up 1 level. `$root` goes all the way to the top level, which without looking at all your code, may not be the correct context.

Comment: thank you, yes I have and it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just looked through your code. It looks fine - I often use a similar pattern, where I have a view model with a list of items, the list is rendered with a foreach, and for each item I have a remove button that calls back up to the $parent.removeSomething function. So, feeling confident, I put your HTML and JS into a fiddle and tweaked a couple of things:

- I used 300 baud's correction, above, to insert the new keyword
- I tweaked your RemoveLineItem function, to show how you don't need to pass in the $index, but instead can make use of the parameters given to you by Knockout - this is the technique described in the item 2 from the Knockout docs that you refer to.

It looks like this:

```
self.RemoveLineItem = function (line_item, event) {
    self.Dtl.remove(line_item);
    alert('RemoveLineItem was called');
};
```

Here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/RUZ4W/

So that works for me... does it work for you? If the Fiddle does work for you, then hopefully it will reassure you that your code is on the right track. The problem could then be caused by something else in your application. Do you have other view models? If you do, you could try commenting out the ko.applyBinding statements and see if you can isolate another view model that's causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
ko.applyBindings(viewModel(orderOne, details, sls));
```

To this line (add `new`):

```
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel(orderOne, details, sls));
```